# List all the sAMAccountName from ldap using java

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I want to get the list of all sAMAccountName from ldap, Below is the method which gives me the Ldap attributes of a user by using samAccountName

```
public static void searchUserFromLdap(String samAccountName) throws Exception{

    SearchResult searchResult = ldapConnection.search("CN=XX,DC=XX,DC=XX", SearchScope.SUB, "(sAMAccountName=" + samAccountName +")"); 

    if(searchResult.getSearchEntries().size()<=0){
        System.out.println("No such user found in LDAP");
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Start :- LDAP attributes for given user\n");
    for(SearchResultEntry searchResultEntry : searchResult.getSearchEntries()){

        System.out.println(searchResultEntry.toLDIFString());
    }

    System.out.println("\nEnd :- LDAP attributes for given user");

}
```

This method accept the samAccountName and returns the ldap attributes for user
I want to get the list of all samAccountName, I have searched for this but i didn't get anything relevent, Can anyone please tell how can i get the list of sAMAccountName.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what `ldapConnection` is. Is it from [unboundid](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/LDAPConnection.html)?

Either way from the look of the method the third parameter is your LDAP search filter. You can simply change this filter to be the following:

```
(objectClass=user)
```

So the method call would be:

```
SearchResult searchResult = ldapConnection.search(
        "CN=XX,DC=XX,DC=XX", 
        SearchScope.SUB, 
        "(objectClass=user)");
```

The `SearchResult` will then contain all users found under `CN=XX,DC=XX,DC=XX`.

If it is from unboundid, then you can add in a 4th parameter to define that you only want the `sAMAccountName` ldap attribute to be returned for each result. So this would be:

```
SearchResult searchResult = ldapConnection.search(
        "CN=XX,DC=XX,DC=XX", 
        SearchScope.SUB, 
        "(objectClass=user)",
        "sAMAccountName");
```

For more details on LDAP search filters see the following resource:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19528-01/819-0997/gdxpo/index.html

Comment: You were right about my answer, I forgot to filter the object class. Good answer.

Comment: you are better off using `objectCategory` [rather than objectClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I  am not sure about the above post as i haven't tried it, But after reading the oracle documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-6402-10/search.htm I modified my search query and it worked, Here is what i have done

```
public static void getListOfAllSamAccountName() throws Exception {
    List<String> samAccountNameList = null;
    SearchResult searchResult = ldapConnection.search(
            "CN=XX,DC=XX,DC=xx", SearchScope.SUB,
            "(sAMAccountName=*)");

    if (searchResult.getSearchEntries().size() <= 0) {
        System.out.println("No such user found in LDAP");
        return;
    }
    samAccountNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("Start :- LDAP attributes for given user\n");
    for (SearchResultEntry searchResultEntry : searchResult
            .getSearchEntries()) {
        Attribute attribute = searchResultEntry
                .getAttribute("sAMAccountName");
        String samAccountName = attribute.getValue();

        samAccountNameList.add(samAccountName);

    }

    if (samAccountNameList != null) {
        System.out
                .println("*******************************List of Same account Name******************************");
        for (String samAccountName : samAccountNameList) {

            System.out.println(samAccountName);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nEnd :- LDAP attributes for given user");

}
```

Comment: I have related question , i am beginner though . ....If there are subdomains (childa,abc.com childb.abc.com, childc.abc.com )and contains same samaccountname(123456789) how the AD is gonna do authentication ?? Is it going to check the subdomains one by one so that user can be authenticated ?? my app uses only samaccountname as login id. What is the password is different for this samaccount in each of the subdomain... ??